# pthread_Join can't return after call pthread_cancel?

Tags: pthreads

I used Eclispse Indigo + CDT 8.0.2 + cygwin to develope a multi-thread systerm, the code is below:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexCmd = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t signalCmd = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void * Func(void * arg)
{
    int iStatus;
    while (1)
    {
        int a = 1;
        pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutexCmd);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexCmd);
        iStatus = pthread_cond_wait(&signalCmd, &mutexCmd);
        if (iStatus) {
                err_abort(iStatus, "signalCmd status error");
        }
        if(arg->Cmd != navi_Go) //Just a command tag;
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pNaviCtrl->mutexCmd));
            continue;
        }
        //do some work
        //.....
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexCmd);
        pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    }
//pthread_detach(pthread_self());
return  NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int iStatus = 0;
    pthread = tid;
     iStatus = pthread_create(&tid;NULL, Func, NULL);
     if(iStatus)
    {
    err_abort(iStatus, "Start pthread error");
    }
    // do some work
    ...
    //Cancel thread
   void * retval;
   iStatus = pthread_cancel(tid) 
   iStatus = pthread_join(tid; &retval);
   if(iStatus){
        err_abort(iStatus,"Stop thread error");
    }
    return iStatus;
}
```

where program run, it stop at "iStatus = pthread_join(tid1; &retval);" couldn't go forward anymore, I think the thread could be happed to deadlock, but can't find the reason. I supposed after call pthread_cancel(), the thread will exit and return to the pthread_join(),
who can tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I found when I remove "pthread_cleanup_push" and "pthread_cleanup_pop every thing is OK，but I'd likai to kown the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put cleanup_push and _pop inside the while loop.  Don't call them more than once.  If you look at them, they are macros that wrap the code between them in { }.  They setup a longjump that is used when you call pthread_cancel.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_cleanup_pop(1)` tells the pthread library to not only pop the cleanup entry off the stack, but to also execute it.  So that call will also implicitly call:

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexCmd);
```

Since you've already unlocked the mutex, that call has undefined behavior (assuming the mutex type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL`).  I imagine that call is just never returning or something.

Note that your code has other problems handing the cleanup - if you execute the `continue` for the loop, you'll call `pthread_cleanup_push()` a second time (or more), which will add another cleanup context.

There may be other problems (I'm not very familiar with `pthread_cancel()`).